# Is it possible for someone to delete/edit work item history entries in Azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

[ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa1Ms.png)

1. Can highlighted area 1 in the image be altogether removed? or
2. highlighted area 2 in the image be modified by someone(admin) from repository?
   Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can highlighted area 1 in the image be altogether removed?

No.  The work item History record is read-only. There is no method to remove or edit it.

> highlighted area 2 in the image be modified by someone(admin) from repository?

Area 2 is manually modified by the user via opening the work item.

Answer (score 0):

Work Items can be deleted. It's not clear from your screen shot what your specific issue is.  MS have this regarding work items:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi Mike, my issue is that somehow area 1 got removed altogether from a work item history and so is the associated description in area 2 of that particular entry.

Secondly for some entries in area 2, the text is modified or missing which was supposed to be there.

I am just looking at a possibility of whether this can be done, if the history is saved in some repo and can be manipulated. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

We manipulated the database with the following sql script:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (100) [PartitionId]
      ,[ArtifactId]
      ,[ArtifactKind]
      ,[CommentId]
      ,[Version]
      ,[Text]
      ,[RenderedText]
      ,[Format]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedOnBehalfOf]
      ,[CreatedOnBehalfDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[IsDeleted]
      ,[ParentId]
      ,[State]
      ,[Properties]
  FROM [<CollectionDatabase>].[dbo].[tbl_CommentWere]
  Where [Text] LIKE '%<searchstring from the comment>%';

UPDATE [<CollectionDatabase>].[dbo].[tbl_CommentWere]
SET [Text] = '<new string, which will be displayed>';
```

you also have to modify the table "CommentLatest" table.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**